# Connection error: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, opencart, sms-gateway, bulksms

getting error when using `OCU TurboSMS` extension with `opencart`.

When I am doing connection setting  this error:

```
Connection error: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```